# linux 2-step verification

Tags: login

Hello is there something like Google's 2-step verification available for Linux? (Using Debian here)

Here is more info on what this is:
http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1056283&topic=1056284

So basically when I want to login I put in my password, open the application on my phone and it gives me a code. The code can be saved on the computer for X number of days, before a new code is required. It can also not be saved.

Is there something similar for Linux logins?

Thank You.

Comment: FYI Google is using RFC4226 for their OTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came across an article that describes in detail how to use the [Google Authenticator API](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/) with SSH. If you follow the steps described in the article, you should be good to go!

http://www.mnxsolutions.com/security/two-factor-ssh-with-google-authenticator.html

Comment: Hey this is even better! I can use the same app for my gmail and my server, perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like: http://barada.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Along with Google's 2-step verification implementation for their web properties, they wrote an open-source PAM module that lets you use the same tools for logging in on a Linux system:

http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/

I haven't actually tried using it, but it should work. One thing to keep in mind is that this requires some files in your home directory for each user; if you have a lot of machines with some shared authentication system (LDAP, AD, RADIUS, etc.) you'll also need to ensure that home directories are shared between all the systems.